# ANOVA calculation using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, anova, statistical-test

Ive searched the web to no avail, but is there a function or library in pyspark that can perform ANOVA and Tukeys HSD? Or would I have to code it from scratch?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the SciPy package for ANOVA in PySpark, e.g. [one-way ANOVA](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html),
and the [statsmodels package for Tukey HSD](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.multicomp.pairwise_tukeyhsd.html) in PySpark as well.

Comment: But would that require me to convert the pyspark dataframe into a pandas dataframe? That would bring all my data to the driver which defeats the purpose of using pyspark dataframes is it not?